# RowUpdate event not actually Upadating Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

My Gridview is a way to get me viewing database table and perform edit and update when needed

the data is actually made of moth , year and DaysPerMonth (workable days count)

all fields are type of `Int`

so to display the current month instead of the int value /format of a given month i am using 
translation with both ways, out of the database -  to display in gridview as month name(string)

```
   public static CultureInfo ILci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("he-IL");

   public static string GetMonthName(int mInt, int mYear=2012)
   {
        DateTime fullDate = new DateTime(mYear, mInt, 2);
        string[] tempDayArray = fullDate.ToString("MMMM", ILci).Split(' ');
        return ILci.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(mInt);

    }
```

and back in to database through the "translator" / formatter

```
    public static int GetMonthAsInt(string mStr)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(mStr, "MMMM", ILci).Month;

    }
```

all stages are ok from begining - view mode 
through Editing - Edit mode 
even when in update mode,

i could check with VS debugger 
the value of the SQL datasource update command  that is actually "Good To Go"
and executing it's command in SQL server query
returns a succcesfull result.

so the problem remains somewhere in end of update or right after the update DataBind();
line at the end 
the error / exeption i am getting is :

**Input string was not in a correct format.**

this is the GV_DaysPerMonth_RowUpdating event handler Code

```
    protected void GV_DaysPerMonth_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        // by recived i ment what is taken by sql command from gridview

        string recivedNameMonth=string.Empty;
        int recivedYears = 0;
        int recivedDprM = 0;
        int RowNo = 0;

        GridViewRow CurRow = GV_DaysPerMonth.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        string[] formValues = new string[CurRow.Cells.Count-1];
        bool note = ((TextBox)(CurRow.Cells[0].Controls[1])).Text != null;
        if (note)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CurRow.Cells.Count-1; i++)
            {
                formValues[i] = ((TextBox)(CurRow.Cells[i].Controls[1])).Text;
            }
            //recivedNameMonth = ((TextBox)(CurRow.Cells[0].Controls[1])).Text;
        }

        RowNo = e.RowIndex + 1;

        recivedNameMonth = formValues[0];
        int Montint = RobCS.RDates.GetMonthAsInt(recivedNameMonth);
        recivedYears = Convert.ToInt32(formValues[1]);
        recivedDprM = Convert.ToInt32(formValues[2]);

        dsWorkDayPerMonth.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE [tblWorkDaysPerMonth] SET [theMonth] = " + Montint+ ", [theYear] = "+recivedYears+",[WorkDaysPerMonth] = " + recivedDprM + " WHERE [recordID] = " + RowNo;

        GV_DaysPerMonth.DataBind();

    }
```

using it on

SqlDataSource

```
<asp:sqldatasource runat="server" id="dsWorkDayPerMonth" 
ConnectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=hental;Integrated Security=True" 
ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblWorkDaysPerMonth]"
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblWorkDaysPerMonth] SET [theMonth] = @theMonth, [theYear] = @theYear, 
                                    [WorkDaysPerMonth] = @WorkDaysPerMonth WHERE [recordID] = @recordID" 
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblWorkDaysPerMonth] WHERE [recordID] = @recordID" 
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblWorkDaysPerMonth]">
<UpdateParameters> 
    <asp:Parameter Name="theMonth" Type="Int32" /> 
    <asp:Parameter Name="theYear" Type="Int32" /> 
    <asp:Parameter Name="WorkDaysPerMonth" Type="Int32" /> 
    <asp:Parameter Name="recordID" Type="Int32" /> 
</UpdateParameters> 
<DeleteParameters> 
    <asp:Parameter Name="recordID" Type="Int32" /> 
</DeleteParameters> 
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

with GridView

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Month" ControlStyle-Width="100" HeaderStyle-Width="120" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"> 
                    <ItemTemplate> 
                        <%# Eval("theMonth")%> 
                    </ItemTemplate> 
                    <EditItemTemplate> 
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TBX_theMonth" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("theMonth")%>' /> 
                    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: If I were you, I would look at the contents of your formValues array and verify that they can be parsed to integers.

Comment: they all did , the probem is the syntax / procidure of the actual update it self. checking the values of data that i collected from every variable /sql parameter just before "executing" the update... i did put it in quotes cause i think my method updating the data base is wrong

Comment: I'm stepping outside of my zone of expertise, here, but I believe that you're not supposed to need to change the text of the `UpdateCommand`.  It's already parameterized.  The question would then be how to provide the parameters to the UpdateCommand, and that I don't know off hand.  (I don't use the SqlDataSource.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it was implemented  in first code example without the requierd

```
       //your connection string here 

        SqlConnection con = RobCS_109.RDB.HentlConn;

        con.Open();
        string updateCMD = dsWorkDayPerMonth.UpdateCommand;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da;

        //use a select command and SqlConnection
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(dsWorkDayPerMonth.SelectCommand, con);

        //same here i have used all values recived in the example(top one)code
        // event -RowUpdating above, then i am using
       //stored sqlUpdate string for the command below
        da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(SQLUP);
        da.Fill(ds, "tblWorkDayPerMonth");


        dsWorkDayPerMonth.Update();


        con.Close();
```

now it does work , if you were having a problem with updating event you can try it as in here 
i will further try later on to improve it via a `using` statemet , as soon as i will learn how